# Understanding top level window property

Tags: javascript

I get a js error when I declare the following script.

```
 <script>
    window.onload=init;
    init = function(){alert("Yahoo!");}
</script>
```

It works when I declare init as:

```
 <script>
    window.onload=init;
    var init = function(){alert("Yahoo!");}
</script>
```

Shouldn't the top level init should implicitly become the property of window object? Please help me understand the concept.

Comment: The second one doesn't "work" - it just doesn't throw an error.

Comment: You should always define init before you attach it to an event, like onload.

Comment: Or use function declaration syntax: `function init() {alert("Yahoo!");}` in which case you can make a forward reference to `init`.

Comment: It's actually a decent question. It is called hoisting. *[link](https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=variable%20hoisting)*.

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript tracks variables and function declarations *before* executing the code. Lots of languages do this, actually, so it's a good thing to get used to.

It does *not*, however, track assignments. That counts as executing the code. Even though when a variable that is not defined is assigned, it becomes a property of `window`, it is *not* a variable! It can be deleted from `window`, unlike real variables.

```
var i = 2;
n = 2;
delete window.i; //false
delete window.n; //true
```

Thus, they can not be used before they are defined like variables. Instead, they must be defined first, and then used. Otherwise, they will not be defined.

```
//OK, but not recommended because init is now not a variable. It makes more sense to make init a variable instead.
init = function(){alert("Yahoo!");}
window.onload=init;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
window.onload=init;
var init = function(){alert("Yahoo!");}
</script>
```

This is organized by Javascript as such (variable declarations first):

```
<script>
var init;
window.onload=init;
init = function(){alert("Yahoo!");}
</script>
```

Thus, `init` is present when used for `onload`.

The one without the `var` doesn't include a variable declaration but an assignment to a property of `window`. Assignments are not changed during preprocessing. So, nothing named `init` is found and execution fails.

Comment: You don't need the `var` in this order: `init = function () alert("Yahoo!");};  window.onload = init;` so it's not just that the `var` keyword is missing.

Answer (score 0):

this is related to the fact that javascript engine makes two passes over a function. at first pass, it moves all the local variables to the top of the function, and in second pass it runs the function.

So, when you define `init` with `var`, it is a local variable, therefore defined in the first pass and successfully run in the second pass.

I'm not sure if i could make it clear, but if you want to get more information on this topic, it was very well covered in [Single Page Web Applications](http://www.manning.com/mikowski/) by Michael S. Mikowski and Josh C. Powell.